# Android local SQLite sync with Firebase

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where the default option is to store user data as a local **SQLite database**, however, I want to add the option if the user wants to sign in and transfer the local database to an online database so it can be accessed on multiple devices.

I don't have much experience with cloud storage solution so any advice would be really appreciated. Is for my application the **Firebase Real-time Database** *the best online solution* or is there another approach I should look into?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firebase's real-time database is indeed one of the best solutions for your problem. It has a generous free plan and is well integrated into Android Studio.
And if your data structure is simple enough, you can drop SQLite altogether and use [Firebase's offline storage](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html). This will allow Firebase to automatically handle syncing of offline data for you(syncing is usually painful to implement by yourself).

Alternatively, you could build your own web app and expose a REST API to your android application. This gives you the advantage of having control over everything. I would however not recommend this because of the amount of knowledge and time required.

Comment: You are correct, firebase is the best solution for simple data structures. However I did find it challenging at first to reconfigure my SQLite data structure to fit with firebase's real time database structure.

Comment: Offiline support is read-only safe. Do not try to enter data offiline because it is not guaranteed that when the network back the data will be inserted in the base of the web Firebase, there are many reports on the web with problems about it. For example, if the user loses offiline authentication you will not be able to authenticate until he enters online and the data entered offiline serious risk correction.

Comment: @kessir : offline capabilities will require everything to be synced with firebase as soon as app loads which can be costly.. however if you only sync the page which is loaded (when syncing sqlite with firebase) it can save you cost and network bandwidth...

Comment: Please see this link to see what I am talking about : https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb